# Return an array of objects containing the Object' information, selected from Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
            /**
          * A prototype to create Animal objects
          */
        function Animal (name, type, breed) {
            this.name = name;
             this.type = type;
             this.breed = breed;
        }

         function createAnimalObjects(names, types, breeds) {
            // IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!
            }
    /* Input should be like this

    a_name = ['Dog','Cat', 'Fowl','Goat'];
    a_type = ['Security Dog', 'Blue Eyes', 'Cock', 'she Goat'];
    a_breed = ['German Shepherd', 'Noiseless', 'African Cock', 'American Goat'];
    createAnimalObjects(a_name,a_type,a_breed);
    */
    /* *
    [Animal{name:'Dog', type:'Security Dog' ,breed:'German Shepherd'},
Animal{name:'Cat', type:'Blue Eyes', breed:'Noiseless'}
......etc]
```

An array should return new animal object, using the above prototype. Please help with commenting your code for clarity. Am a learner.

Comment: `// IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!` ?? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation

```js
function Animal (name, type, breed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.breed = breed;
}

function createAnimalObjects(names, types, breeds) {
    if ([...arguments].some(({length}) => length !== names.length)) throw new Error('length doesnt match');
    return names.map((e, i) => new Animal(e, types[i], breeds[i]));
}

a_name = ['Dog','Cat', 'Fowl','Goat'];
a_type = ['Security Dog', 'Blue Eyes', 'Cock', 'she Goat'];
a_breed = ['German Shepherd', 'Noiseless', 'African Cock', 'American Goat'];

console.log(createAnimalObjects(a_name, a_type, a_breed));
```

Comment: Thanks boss , please can you explain the logic behind this operation '' names.map((e, i) => new Animal(e, types[i], breeds[i]));''

Answer (score 0):

When you want to combine multiple arrays it is usually done by a zip function:

```js
const zip = (...arrays) =>
  [
    ...new Array(
      Math.max(...arrays.map((array) => array.length)),
    ).keys(),
  ].map((index) =>
    arrays.reduce(
      (result, array) => result.concat(array[index]),
      [],
    ),
  );

console.log(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]));
```

Now you can use zip to combine the arrays and then map to an array of Animal values

```js
const zip = (...arrays) =>
  [
    ...new Array(//.keys returns iterator, spread this to new array
      Math.max(...arrays.map((array) => array.length)),//longest array
    ).keys(),
  ].map((index) =>
    arrays.reduce(
      (result, array) => result.concat(array[index]),
      [],
    ),
  );

const a_name = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fowl', 'Goat'];
const a_type = ['Security Dog','Blue Eyes','Cock','she Goat'];
const a_breed = ['German Shepherd','Noiseless','African Cock','American Goat'];

function Animal(name, type, breed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.breed = breed;
}

console.log(
  //zip returns [[names[0],types[0],breeds[0]],[names[1],types[1],breeds[1],...]
  zip(a_name, a_type, a_breed) 
    .map(
      ([name, type, breed]) =>//destructure [name,type,breed]
        new Animal(name, type, breed),
    ),
);
```

Some documentation: [destructure syntax](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#destructuring), [spread](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#spreadrest), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)